# Как добавить конкретное слово в словарь Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office

Как добавить конкретное слово в словарь Word?

Comment: Что Ты под этим подразумеваешь?

Comment: У меня есть переменная типа string. В ней хранится некоторое слово. Это слово надо в словарь MS Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Word._Application word = new Word.Application();
            word.Documents.Add();
            string dictfilename=word.CustomDictionaries.ActiveCustomDictionary.Path+"\\"+word.CustomDictionaries.ActiveCustomDictionary.Name;
            FileStream fs;
            try
            {
                fs = new FileStream(dictfilename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                Console.WriteLine("Открыт файл " + dictfilename);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Не могу открыть файл словаря " + dictfilename);
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs,Encoding.UTF8);
            sw.WriteLine("rihgths");
            sw.Close();
            word.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Минус этого подхода в том, что для работы этого кода необходим установленный ворд на машине. Я бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону OpenXml, потому что он надежнее.

Comment: Пользовательский словарь Word представляет собой текстовый файл в кодировке UTF-8. Чем в работе с ним может помочь OpenXML?
Сам Word используется исключительно для того, чтобы получить путь к пользовательскому словарю (в моем примере по умолчанию), и варианта как сделать это без установленного Word я не знаю, честно говоря. Нет, конечно можно создание word вынести в try, а в catch просить ввести имя файла словаря... но что-то мне подсказывает, что вопрос у человека был в другом :)

Comment: >Пользовательский словарь Word представляет собой текстовый файл в кодировке UTF-8.

@Zufir чем бы он там ни был, ваше решение подразумевает, что на машине должен быть установлен MS Word. Использование Open XML этого не требует. Более того, есть сомнения в том, что ваше решение будет работоспособно для Word, начиная с версии 2007

Comment: @DreamChild, у меня установлен Word 2010, решение работает. Возможно, оно не будет работать с Office 2013, в котором поменялся модуль спеллчекинга. Завтра проверю на работе, там у меня 2013. 
Чем при работе с текстовым файлом, не являющимся документом Office поможет OpenXML - мне по прежнему непонятно. Объекты Office не используются для записи в файл - они используются только для определения местонахождения этого файла. Но да. Можно вынести получение словаря в один метод, а запись - в другой, и перегрузить метод записи относительно типа словаря. Правда, тогда слово Word в вопросе будет лишним